# How to remove a key from a RethinkDB document?

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python

I'm trying to remove a key from a RethinkDB document.
My approaches (which didn't work):

```
r.db('db').table('user').replace(function(row){delete row["key"]; return row})
```

Other approach:

```
r.db('db').table('user').update({key: null})
```

This one just sets row.key = null (which looks reasonable).

Examples tested on *rethinkdb data explorer* through web UI.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Here's the relevant example from the documentation on RethinkDB's website: http://rethinkdb.com/docs/cookbook/python/#removing-a-field-from-a-document

To remove a field from all documents in a table, you need to use `replace` to update the document to not include the desired field (using `without`):

```
r.db('db').table('user').replace(r.row.without('key'))
```

To remove the field from one specific document in the table:

```
r.db('db').table('user').get('id').replace(r.row.without('key'))
```

You can change the selection of documents to update by using any of the selectors in the API (http://rethinkdb.com/api/), e.g. `db`, `table`, `get`, `get_all`, `between`, `filter`.

Comment: If you are looking for the javascript version of the recipe:
http://rethinkdb.com/docs/cookbook/javascript/#removing-a-field-from-a-document

Comment: How can I do this for nested field of key?

Comment: @Suvitruf, you can use the nested field syntax as follows: `.replace(r.row.without({key1: {key2: true}}))`

Comment: How do I delete a nested property? like `without('foo.bar.baz')` to delete the `baz` property?

Answer (score 12):

You can use `replace` with `without`:

```
r.db('db').table('user').replace(r.row.without('key'))
```

Comment: How can I do this for nested field of key?

Comment: For nested fields, you can use the nested field syntax as follows: `.replace(r.row.without({key1: {key2: true}}))`

Comment: How do I combine this with also updating the value of another key?

Comment: What does the `true` do here?

Answer (score 6):

You do not need to use replace to update the entire document.
Here is the relevant documentation: [ReQL command: literal](https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/literal/)

Assume your user document looks like this:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Alice",
  "data": {
    "age": 19,
    "city": "Dallas",
    "job": "Engineer"
  }
}
```

And you want to remove age from the data property. Normally, update will just merge your new data with the old data.  r.literal can be used to treat the data object as a single unit.

```
r.table('users').get(1).update({ data: r.literal({ age: 19, job: 'Engineer' }) }).run(conn, callback)

// Result passed to callback
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Alice",
  "data": {
    "age": 19,
    "job": "Engineer"
  }
}
```

or

```
r.table('users').get(1).update({ data: { city: r.literal() } }).run(conn, callback)

// Result passed to callback
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Alice",
  "data": {
    "age": 19,
    "job": "Engineer"
  }
}
```