# How to delete elements of a table in Rethinkdb from Data Explorer?

Tags: javascript, delete-row, rethinkdb-javascript

I have an application created in Node.js with a Rethinkdb database, I load images from the application, but from the Data Explorer, to which you can connect from localhost: 8080, I can not delete the loaded elements.

```js
// This is how I show the elements that the table has Data Explorer
r.db("xxxxxxxxxx").table('images')
// And this is, or that shows
{
  "createdAt": Sun Jul 29 2018 16:19:27 GMT+00:00 ,
  "id": "17aac165-e885-4278-9cf2-8a71bca65fe3" ,
  "publicId": "0IERfW4T5wfcjhFjGNftZh" ,
  "src": https:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx1532881165551.jpg, »
  "tags": [ ],
  "user": {
    "avatar": "www.gravatar.com/avatar/c17a64a79d5bb880c9b002458240fa92" ,
    "name": "" ,
    "username": "pedrito"
  },
  "userId": "pedrito"
}
```

For more than what I check the javascript documentation of Rethinkdb: (https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/)

I can not find a way to remove the elements of the images from the table one by one. It's there, but I cannot find the way. The most I can see is how to remove users from another table: r.db ("xxxxxxxx"). Table ("users"). Filter (r.row ['username'] = 'pedrito'). delete (). runpero

I can not delete the images in the same way. I want to do it from Data Explorer, from the graphical part of Rethinkdb. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This question is a bit unclear, if you mean deleting the entire document:

`r.db("database").table("table").get("document_id").delete()`
**database**, **table**, and **document_id** are placeholders
**database**: The database the table you are trying to delete from is in
**table**: The table the document you want to delete is in
**document_id**: The primary key of the document (default `id`) that you want to delete
so in this

`{
    "createdAt": Sun Jul 29 2018 16:19:27 GMT+00:00 ,
    "id": "17aac165-e885-4278-9cf2-8a71bca65fe3" ,
     "publicId": "0IERfW4T5wfcjhFjGNftZh" ,
     "src": https:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx1532881165551.jpg, »
     "tags": [ ],
     "user": {
      "avatar": "www.gravatar.com/avatar/c17a64a79d5bb880c9b002458240fa92" ,
      "name": "" ,
      "username": "pedrito"
     } ,
     "userId": "pedrito"
    }`

Your primary key is likely ID, so you would use
`r.db("xxx").table("images").get("17aac165-e885-4278-9cf2-8a71bca65fe3").delete()`

https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/#delete

---

#### else, if you mean deleting a specific key, go check this answer to another question https://stackoverflow.com/a/18580552

### EDIT: Delete all

`r.db('database').table('table').forEach((entry)=>{
    return r.db('database').table('table').get(entry('id')).delete();
});`

this will delete absolutely **EVERYTHING** in the table!

### EDIT: Delete where key = value

`r.db('database').table('table').filter({key:"value"}).forEach((entry)=>{
    return r.db('database').table('table').get(entry('id')).delete();
});`

This would delete everything in the table where `key`: "value".

Comment: Thanks @Donovan_DMC, it works perfectly to eliminate the elements individually, I would just learn, how to eliminate all at once.

Comment: @gemita added a little code that would delete every entry in the table, check updated answer.

Comment: @gemita also added a query where it will delete all where key:value (last one)

Comment: thank you @Donovan_DMV, I apologize for the time it took me to answer, I could not connect until now. Thanks for the support.